# C# form adding to lists

Tags: c#

if any one is able to help thanks, it will only run after it crashes and im not sure how to fix it thanks

```
{
    //DOES NOT WORK YET
    foreach (Client c in records)
        if (nameBox.Text != c.Name)
        {
          records.Add(c);
        }
        else
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Member Already Exists");
        }           
}
```

Comment: What's the error you are receiving when it crashes?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to modify the same collection that you are iterating over, which is not allowed. While it's not clear what you are actually trying to do, you might want to check with something like:

```
var clientName = nameBox.Text.Trim(); // after validating that it's not null or empty
if (!records.Any(c => string.Equals(c.Name, clientName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
{
     records.Add(new Client { Name = clientName } );
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Member already exists");
}
```